# Preconditiong the Biconjugate gradient stabilized method

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

I am solving the equation $A\textbf{x} =\textbf{b}$, however due to the size of the system being large, the best way of performing this is via conjugate gradient methods.

I have implemented the [biconjugate gradient stabilized method from wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biconjugate_gradient_stabilized_method) and have confirmed that it is calculating correctly. However, the condition number of my system is poor so I am interested in applying a preconditioner to the system.

To do this a preconditioner $K = K_1K_2\approx A$ is required, and the matrices $K$ and $K_1$ are explicitly used in the algoithm. However, if I were to pick a preconditioner such as the [Jacobi preconditioner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preconditioner#Jacobi_(or_diagonal)_preconditioner), how would I convert this into the format used in th BiCGStab method? I am assuming that in this case, $K$ is the Jacobi preconditioner, however I am unsure what $K_1$ or $K_2$ are.

Comment: I took the liberty of adjusting your tags. I replaced linear-algebra (which does not apply) with numerical methods which together with numerical-linear-algebra are *the* tags to use here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the case of the Jacobi preconditioner, i.e., a diagonal matrix it makes no particular sense to factor it as a product of two matrices. In fact, the necessary increase in memory traffic will almost certainly slow down the execution of your solver.

However, there are many preconditioners $K$ for which a factorization $K = K_1K_2$ is sensible, see below.

When choosing a preconditioner $K$ your objective is two-fold. You want $K$ to be a nonsingular matrix such that $K^{-1}$ is a good approximation of $A^{-1}$ and you want to be able to compute the action of $K^{-1}$ rapidly, i.e., solve linear systems of the form $Kx=f$.

Now a preconditioner obtained through an incomplete LU factorization is common technique which can be quite effective for certain classes of matrices. It produces sparse matrices L and U, where L is lower triangular and U is upper triangular and $A \approx LU$.

Frequently, but not universally, $L^{-1}AU^{-1}$ or $U^{-1}L^{-1}A$ or $A U^{-1} L^{-1}$ are good approximations of the identity and the appropriate version of preconditioned BiCGStab will do a good job. You need to solve systems of the form $Ux=f$ and $Ly=g$, but this can be done using backward and forward substitution.